# How to deal with missing JSON key when using SuperObject to get key values?

Tags: json, superobject

Using SuperObject in Delphi 2009.
How do I deal with the situation of accessing the string value of a JSON key that might not exist?

eg with this sample code JSONgood has a key 'key2' and a value for it but JSONbad doesn't have a 'key2'
and so evaluates to nil and causes an error when I try to convert it to a string.
Is there a simple way to either convert the nil to a string value or detect it before I try to read it as a string and not read it?

```
var
  ParsedJSON : ISuperObject;
  s : string;
  JSONgood, JSONbad: string; 
begin
   JSONgood, = ''
   +' {                     '
   +' "key1": "one",        '
   +' "key2": "not missing" '
   +' }                     ' 
   ParsedJSON := SOJSONgood, 
   s := ParsedJSON ['key2'].AsString;
   showmessage(s);

  JSONbad: = ''
   +' {                     '
   +' "key1": "one"        '
   +' }                     ' 
   ParsedJSON := SOJSONbad: 
   s := ParsedJSON ['key2'].AsString;  //key 2 does not exist so ParsedJSON ['key2'] is nil
   showmeassage(s);
end;
```

Incidentally I did try to use X-Superobject as I understood that could deal with this  but that complained that it couldn't find RegularExpressions or RTTI named in the uses clause of unit XSuperJSON, so I guess it won't work in Delphi 2009 (and I cannot afford the later Delphi versions)

edit -
Adding

```
If Assigned(ParsedJSON ['key2']) then ...
```

seemed to do it but is this the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I came up with.

It works a bit like the MySQL function `IFNULL(Value, DefaultValueIfNull)` and will return either the string value associated with the key passed or, of the key doesn't exist, it returns the substitute text passed into the function

```
function MissingKeySafeStr(theobject: ISuperObject; key: string; SubstituteText: string) : string;
   begin
   if theobject[key] = nil then
     Result :=  SubstituteText
   else
     Result :=  theobject[key].AsString
   end;
```

**usage**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
   s : string;
   obj : ISuperObject;
begin
 s := '{"name":"jim"}';
 obj := SO(s);
 ShowMessage(MissingKeySafeStr(obj,'age', 'age key missing'));  //displays ''age key missing'
 ShowMessage(MissingKeySafeStr(obj,'name, 'name key missing'));  //displays 'jim'
```

end;